# Array map returning array of undefined when should return array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays

Why does

`['a', 'b', 'c'].map((x) => { letter: x })` returns a array of undefined

and

`['a', 'b', 'c'].map((x) => [{ letter: x }][0])` returns a array of objects correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because

- You use the curly brackets as [block statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions).
- You have `letter` as a [label](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/label).
- `x` is just a value without some action.
- The return of `undefined` is the standard return value of a [function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions) without any return statement with value.

  > To return a value other than the default, a function must have a [`return`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/return) statement that specifies the value to return. A function without a return statement will return a default value. In the case of a [constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/constructor) called with the [`new`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new) keyword, the default value is the value of its this parameter. For all other functions, the default return value is undefined.

Correct call for mapping objects.

```js
console.log(['a', 'b', 'c'].map(x => ({ letter: x })));
```

Comment: This is the answer I was looking for, not just "you should do this way to make it work"... Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

You need to wrap object in `()`

```js
var result = ['a', 'b', 'c'].map((x) => ({ letter: x }))
console.log(result)
```

Comment: Thans for your answer :)

Answer (score 1):

A function that lacks an explicit return statement will return undefined.
`() => {}` is equivalent to `function(){}`.
`x => x` is equivalent to `function(x){ return x;}`

So arrow function without `{}` will return computed value of the expression.