# Array mapping returns array of undefined object

Tags: d3.js

Here is the beginning of my function:

```
    d3.csv("Sales Export Friendly 2-14-2017.csv", function(data) {      
    sales = data.map(function(d) { return +d.bookingID, +d.totalPaid ; });
```

I am wondering why despite my best efforts, I can't get the columns with headers "bookingID" and "totailPaid" from the csv file into an array of 2 columns which I can select with sale[0] and sale[1] later in the function as so:

```
var x = d3.scaleBand()
    .domain(sales.map(function(sale){ return sale[0]; }))
    .range([0, width])
    .paddingInner([0.1])

var y = d3.scaleLinear()
  .range([height, 0])
  .domain([0, d3.max(sales.map(function(sale){ return sale[1]; }))]);
```

I read this Q&A: [Array map returning array of undefined when should return array of objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39280299/array-map-returning-array-of-undefined-when-should-return-array-of-objects) but am still having issues

Comment: Look at your [last question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42291605/unexpected-value-nan-parsing-y-attribute). You have to put the square brackets: `sales = data.map(function(d) { return [+d.bookingID, +d.totalPaid]; });`

Comment: I still get an of arrays with all (2) undefined values

Comment: Please copy your CSV structure (just the first couple of rows is enough). Keep in mind that bookingID and totalPaid are two headers that I created for my bogus data in your last question. You have to use **your** headers.